# How to notify main thread of an event in child thread?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a child thread in which an event is fired after certain time , so when the event is fired in child thread , how can i notify the main thread about the same and call a function in main thread?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)? (Without more context you are unlikely to get any useful answers, you likely need to use something like a [SynchronoizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) but without showing what you are trying to accomplish I can't be more specific than that)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `WaitHandle` derived class to communicate between the main and child threads:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManualResetEvent handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Thread thread = new Thread(o =>
            {
                WorkBeforeEvent();
                handle.Set();
                WorkAfterEvent();
                Console.WriteLine("Child Thread finished");

            });
        thread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread waiting for event from child");
        handle.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread notified of event from child");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void WorkBeforeEvent()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Before Event");
    }

    public static void WorkAfterEvent()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("After Event");
    }
}
```